# How to count specified word occurrence in multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I have some amount of elements with class of "shoutbox_text", how canI count specified word occurrence in all of them? 
(Inner HTML of them is just plain text, there isn't anymore tags inside.)

Comment: E.g.: split that text by whitespace, so that you have an array of words and loop over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to search the word "word", you'd do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('shoutbox_text'),
    n = 0;
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
  var text = elems[i].innerHTML;
  n += (text.match(/word/gi) || []).length;   
}
alert(n);
```

If you have the word in a variable `word`, and the search is case sensitive you could do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('shoutbox_text'),
    n = 0;
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
  var text = elems[i].innerHTML;
  n += text.split(word).length - 1;   
}
alert(n);
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Anyway, the second code worked when i added " and " after and before "word" in "split(word)". Thanks

Comment: Eyup. I was going to do this after blockade disappeared :D